# Templates: statically typed or dynamic?

Tags: c++, templates, type-systems

C++ is considered statically typed. I understand that.

I don't understand how that applies to templates.

Here is a simple example of a type that cannot be determined at compile time:

```
template <typename... t>
struct foo {
  using type = typename foo<t..., t...>::type;
};

foo<int>::type x; // type of x cannot be determined without running meta-program
```

I presume there are cases where it's impossible to detect type errors without solving the halting problem.

**So my question is, why aren't templates considered dynamically typed?**

Comment: There is no meta-programm running, just some type instantiations, all happening at the **compile time** of the C++ programm.

Comment: @Xeo it can't instantiate anything as it can't determine the type

Comment: I assume compiler will still try to figure out that type in compiling time. Any proof against the assumption?

Comment: What do you mean "the type of `x` cannot be determined"? The type is written left of `x` in the declaration, it is `foo<int>::type`!

Comment: @Xeo, templates are turing complete (subject to running time limitations), and so one can rightly call the templates a meta-program, interpreted at compile time, which produces the concrete types used by the real program

Comment: @AndréCaron That's a type alias, the actual type is not `foo<int>::type`.

Comment: @Pubby: `foo<int>::type` is a type, regardless of the fact that it is an alias for something else.  You can use it to declare variables (like `x`) just as you can for any other type, such as `int`.  If the code compiles, the complete type may be manually expanded to something very ugly, which is probably why it was written the way it is in the first place, but it still is a type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Static/dynamic typing typically refers to the behavior at runtime of the final compiled program, not of the meta-program. Since `foo<int>::type` is resolved by the time you reach runtime of the final compiled program, it's considered statically typed.

As for the template metaprogram, one could consider it to be using duck typing, which is a kind of dynamic typing. Note, however, that there are still static types (in pre-C++11) - the number of template arguments on a template can be considered a meta-type for a meta-function that produces a concrete type (which is a value as far as the meta-program is concerned).

By comparison, in Haskell, they have a concept of a hierarchy of types. You have typical types - things like functions, integers, etc. Then you have 'kinds', which describe types and meta-functions on types. For example, the Haskell kind `* -> * -> *` could refer to a mapping of keys to values, much like a `template<typename Key, typename Value> class Map` in C++. Any determination on whether the language is statically or dynamically typed then would have to refer to which level of the hierarchy you're referring to. Historically, C++ templates were never really thought of as meta-programs when they were first designed, so this kind of terminology isn't as widely used in C++, but the same concepts can still be applied.

Comment: I don't see how the metaprogram is dynamically typed. Templates use structural typing, which is a kind of static typing.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, the dynamic typing comes into play when you reference types relative to a template argument. eg, `std::vector<T::foo>` where `T` is a template argument; the compiler must verify that `T::foo` exists, is a type, and is if the proper kind, dynamically (ie, while executing the template meta-program, rather than prior to executing the template meta-program)

Comment: No, `T::foo` is a value, not a type. That's why you need `typename` as a disambiguator: to know without instantiating (i.e. running the metaprogram).

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, `T::foo` could also be a function (ie, template member class) as well, however. And when we use such functions, we must verify their type (number of parameters) at meta-runtime.

Comment: To convince me you need to show me a C++ program with a non-instantiated template that has a type error and yet compiles. The type error must not depend on input: an error that depends on a type parameter corresponds to a "real program" rejecting invalid input and thus is not relevant: we all know you can't validate input at compile-time. I have now realized that the first lookup phase does not do all the checking I thought it does, and so you can write such a program :( There's a bunch of static checking, but not as much as feasible (either that or my compilers are not conforming).